# Needs hints or help for a complex analysis question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, analyticity, singularity

I am having problem with the following question.

Have:

1. $f(z)$ be analytic on an open set $\Omega$ with $\overline{\Delta(0, r)} \subset \Omega$.
2. for zeros of $f$ in $\Delta(0, r)$ are $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n}$
3. $$
   g(z)=\frac{r^{2}-\overline{a_{1}} z}{r\left(z-a_{1}\right)} \cdot \frac{r^{2}-\overline{a_{2}} z}{r\left(z-a_{2}\right)} \cdots \frac{r^{2}-\overline{a_{n}} z}{r\left(z-a_{n}\right)} f(z)
   $$

Asking for:

1. How to prove that the function $g(z)$ is is analytic on $\overline{\Delta(0, r)}$ except for removable singularities and does not vanish on $\Delta(0, r)$?
2. How to prove that $|g(z)|=|f(z)|$ for all $z$ with $|z|=r$?

> All the zeros should be removable singularities, right? Then how to determine if it vanishes on $\Delta(0, r)$? or not.

Comment: Look up automorphisms of the unit disk. This is just a rescaling of that.

Comment: Since $r^{2}-\overline{a_{k}} z$ doesn't vanish on the disc and the zeroes of $f$ are cancelled by the denominators, it is clear that $G$ is analytic and has no zeroes there, while an easy computation shows that $\frac{r^{2}-\overline{a_{1}} z}{r\left(z-a_{1}\right)} $ has modulus one on the boundary circle $|z|=r$ giving $|f|=|g|$ there